# Plot standard error bars from mixed model using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I want to plot (using ggplot2) linear mixed effects model (lmer function from lme4) together with error bars representing standard errors. Here is the model:

```
m1 <- lmer(repinterv ~ prevoutc * outcome * prevtask + (1|id), p1)
```

Repinterv is a continuous dependent variable, while three factors are binary, within-subjects. Each line of the data frame is a single experimental trial.

While I have a working line to make a fit for each effect and interaction, I'm really strugling with error bars.

```
p1$fit = model.matrix(m1) %% fixef (m1) # fits
p1$fitse = model.matrix(m1) %% coef(summary(m1))[,2] # standard errors
```

The first line here calculates the fitted values for each level of the model. I tried to use it for standard errors from model's summary, but the problem is that while fixed effects are presented as the relative difference from the intercept, SE are the actual values (as I understand it). If I use this method then I get summed standard errors for each fit, instead of the actual value from coef(summary(m1)).

```
ggplot(p1, aes(x = outcome, y = fit, fill = prevoutc)) +  # grouped bar plot
facet_wrap(~ prevtask, labeller = gridlab) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar", position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-fitse, ymax=fit+fitse), width = 0.1, size =0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Can you please tip me if I should use some other operator or a different method to subtract SE for this model?

---

Edit:
Below are the coefficients of my model. I want to plot estimates and corresponding standard errors.

```
                              Estimate Std. Error   t value
(Intercept)                  335.69881  16.190304 20.734558
prevoutc1                     10.74602   7.143445  1.504318
outcome1                      37.36665   8.471898  4.410659
prevtask1                     12.92135   7.330930  1.762580
prevoutc1:outcome1           -14.39956   9.338283 -1.541992
prevoutc1:prevtask1           17.37322  10.491121  1.655993
outcome1:prevtask1           -29.37134   9.957079 -2.949795
prevoutc1:outcome1:prevtask1  14.75692  13.539756  1.089896
```

And that's the plot I currently have: [image: 3 factors]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to plot population-level predictions with associated standard errors? You can't use the coefficient's SE for this. See https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/147

Comment: I basically want to plot estimates with corresponding standard errors - I edited main question so you can see the coefficients. If it's a wrong way to go, then what is the alternative?

Comment: What estimates do you want to plot? Your edit doesn't clarify anything for me.

Comment: I wan to plot all three factors that I have in model, i.e. all estimates from coef(summary(m1)) which I show in the question (together with current plot now).

Comment: No, what the plot shows are not the coefficients. You plot fitted values / predictions there. See [this FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions) for how to get the desired SEs.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much for this FAQ, that helped. 
But what is actually the difference between fitted values that I plot and coefficients from my model - is it just the fact that the latter are relative to the intercept (numerically that's the case)? And what, then is the difference between SEs from my coefficients table and those calculated in the FAQ (i.e. why can't I just use coefficient's SE in here)?

Comment: because coefficients are correlated.